# ressource name causing issues

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I keep having errors with a ressource name, here his what I have so far :
(I rails generator for model and controller BTW)

- model filename : `sarl_legal_status.rb`
- model class name : `SarlLegalStatus`
- controller filename : `sarl_legal_statuses_controller.rb`
- controller class name : `SarlLegalStatusesController`

I even tested with added inflections like :

```
inflect.plural 'status', 'statuses'
inflect.singular 'statuses', 'status'
```

or

```
inflect.irregular 'status', 'statuses'
```

### Here are the kind of errors i got

#### routing issues

if I set my route like this

```
root 'sarlLegalStatuses#new'
```

I get

```
in check_controller_and_action': 'sarlLegalStatuses' is not a supported controller name.
```

I can "solve" this by writing `root 'sarl_legal_statuses#new'` instead

#### path issues

in the `new.html.erb` view file i put

```
<%= form_for(@sarlLegalStatus) do |f|
  f.text_field :companyName
  f.number_field :price, in: 1..99, step: 1
end %>
```

and I get

```
undefined method `sarl_legal_statuses_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f0728975910>:0x007f0728982d40>
```

I don't understand what I might have done wrong, can you help me please ?

ps: currently the title is quite bad, I will change it in the future when I know more and I am very open to suggestions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you defined the resources :sarl_legal_statuses in the route.rb ?

Comment: No I did not as SarlLegalStatus was not fully fonctional and I didnot want the default routes to be generated. I added the line and it is working now I guess now that the use of "form_for" need it to be declared as a ressource, I will have to a different helper if I don't want to use the default routing right ? And thank you very much you totally unlocked the situation !

Comment: if you do not want to use deafult routes you can use
    <%=for_for "sarl_legal_status",url:{:action=>''create"} do |f|%>
    <%end%>